# Headless Chrome not detecting css and Background image of the webpage

Tags: css, angularjs-directive, headless-browser

My pdf page don't take background image and any CSS of the page. Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/#/signIn', 
  {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0});
  await page.waitFor(20000);
  await page.pdf({path: 'sigview.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

It should take complete web page layout with all CSS

Answer (score 1):

By default, when saving your page as PDF Puppeteer would use `print` styles, which you're mostly missing (I've seen there's bunch of them, but nothing that would style the login page, AFAIK). But there's a solution to this. First, force screen emulation in puppeteer

```
 await page.emulateMedia('screen');
```

and then add some `printBackground: true` property to your pdf method call. Without it Puppeteer will ignore background images (that's default behaviour)

```
await page.pdf({path: 'sigview.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true});
```

As a result, you would have something like that:

```
await page.emulateMedia("screen");
await page.pdf({
  path: "sigview.pdf",
  format: "A4",
  printBackground: true
});
```

More reading on PDF options [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions)

BTW, is there any reason why set `20000` as value of `waitFor`?

Comment: Note that `emulateMedia` has been renamed to `emulateMediaType` in newer version of puppeteer.