# Images dont load when i call pdf method in page of puppeteer

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

How do I get the pupperter to generate a PDF with page images ?

```
const navegador = await pup.launch();
const pagina = await navegador.newPage();
await pagina.goto(URL);
await pagina.emulateMedia('print');
await pagina.pdf({ path: 'arquivos/pagina1.pdf', format: 'A4' });
```

Comment: see if solution from this post help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373194/headless-chrome-not-detecting-css-and-background-image-of-the-webpage/57374779#57374779

Comment: I was unsuccessful with this solution, thanks. I will try to find another solution.
@AdamKosmala

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?